# Calculate matrix $X$ in expression $X + B = (A-B)X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have to calculate matrix $X$ in expression $X + B = (A-B)X$.

$$ A=\left[
    \begin{array}
        k1 & -2 & 3\\
        2 & 4 &0\\
        -1 & 2 & 1\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$$ B=\left[
    \begin{array}
        k0 & 1 & 3\\
        2 & -3 &1\\
        1 & 3 & -1\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I have no idea how to even begin here, I know basic operations with matrices and inverses, but I'm pretty much clueless here.. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use linearity of matrix multiplication:
$$X + B = (A-B)X \\
B = (A-B)X - X = (A-B-I)X \\
X = (A-B-I)^{-1}B$$
Where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

If you want to check your result, doing this calculation results in
$$X = \frac16 \pmatrix{-9&-5&-15\\0&-2&-6\\-12&6&-42}$$

Comment: Just make sure that $(A-B-I)$ is invertible.

Comment: @LeonAragones I'll leave that to the OP for checking, the matrices are given explicitly so anyone can check ;)

Comment: I actually made an edit, because I swtiched two of them up, so it actually is invertible! Thanks for the answer tho, I appreciate it!

Comment: @NejcPisk I just noticed, so I rolled back my edit. Here's a check-up:
$$X = \frac16 \pmatrix{-9&-5&-15\\0&-2&-6\\-12&6&-42}$$

Answer (score 0):

Even if $A-B-I$ were not invertible (as in the original question), we always can solve the $9$ linear equations given by the matrix equation in the $9$ variables of $X$. In the current version we obtain
\begin{align*}
3x_2 & = 0, \\
3x_5 + 1 & = 0\\
\cdots & = \cdots \\
2x_7 + x_8 - x_9 - 1 & = 0.
\end{align*}

Solving this linear system of equations gives the solution, namely $x_1=-9/6$, $x_2=0$, ..., $x_9=-42/6$. Of course, in the current version, we just have
$$
X=(A-B-I)^{-1}B.
$$

Comment: You should say how you number the elements of $X$ if you don't use $x_{ij}$ as a notation. $x_{1,k}$ will not appear in any equation in the end for any $k$.

Comment: The notation is, for columns of $X$, $(x_1,x_2,x_3), (x_4,x_5,x_6), (x_7,x_8,x_9)$. Check with the other answers, the solutions agree (i.e., $x_2=0$ etc.).

Comment: Nevermind, I thought your equations were intended for the singular case. Sorry.